# How to make a list of lists in Python when it has multiple separators?

Tags: python, list, readfile, strip

The sample file looks like this (all on one line, wrapped for legibility):

```
 ['>1\n', 'TCCGGGGGTATC\n', '>2\n', 'TCCGTGGGTATC\n',
  '>3\n', 'TCCGTGGGTATC\n', '>4\n', 'TCCGGGGGTATC\n',
  '>5\n', 'TCCGTGGGTATC\n', '>6\n', 'TCCGTGGGTATC\n',
  '>7\n', 'TCCGTGGGTATC\n', '>8\n', 'TCCGGGGGTATC\n','\n',
  '$$$\n', '\n',
  '>B1\n', 'ATCGGGGGTATT\n', '>B2\n', 'TT-GTGGGAATC\n',
  '>3\n', 'TTCGTGGGAATC\n', '>B4\n', 'TT-GTGGGTATC\n',
  '>B5\n', 'TTCGTGGGTATT\n', '>B6\n','TTCGGGGGTATC\n',
  '>B7\n', 'TT-GTGGGTATC\n', '>B8\n', 'TTCGGGGGAATC\n',
  '>B9\n', 'TTCGGGGGTATC\n','>B10\n', 'TTCGGGGGTATC\n',
  '>B42\n', 'TT-GTGGGTATC\n']
```

The `$$$`  separates the two sets. I need to use `.strip` function and remove the `\n` and all the "headers".

I need to make a list of lists (as below) and replace "-" with Z (again, all on one line; wrapped here for legibility):

```
  [['TCCGGGGGTATC','TCCGTGGGTATC','TCCGTGGGTATC', 'TCCGGGGGTATC',
    'TCCGTGGGTATC',CGTGGGTATC','TCCGTGGGTATC', 'TCCGGGGGTATC'],
   ['ATCGGGGGTATT', 'TT-GTGGGAATC','TTCGTGGGAATC', 'TT-GTGGGTATC',
    'TTCGTGGGTATT', 'TTCGGGGGTATC','TT-GTGGGTATC', 'TTCGGGGGAATC',
    'TTCGGGGGTATC', 'TTCGGGGGTATC','TT-GTGGGTATC]]
```

Comment: Where are you stuck?

Comment: If you are dealing with (a variant of) FASTA format, you'd simplify life for everyone if you mentioned this.

Comment: Some quotes and the B in B3 seems to be missing, can you please proofread the examples?

Comment: No, I put it that way because when we get research files, the headers can be pretty muddled up .. so the codes should not be header specific

Comment: You still lack quotes in the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a variation of Moses Koledoye's answer which examines the first character for `>` and discards any matches as well as any empty elements.  I also included replacing "-" with "Z".

```
lst = ['>1\n', 'TCCGGGGGTATC\n', '>2\n', 'TCCGTGGGTATC\n',
   '>3\n', 'TCCGTGGGTATC\n', '>4\n', 'TCCGGGGGTATC\n',
   '>5\n', 'TCCGTGGGTATC\n', '>6\n', 'TCCGTGGGTATC\n',
   '>7\n', 'TCCGTGGGTATC\n', '>8\n', 'TCCGGGGGTATC\n','\n',
   '$$$\n', '\n',
   '>B1\n', 'ATCGGGGGTATT\n', '>B2\n', 'TT-GTGGGAATC\n',
   '>3\n', 'TTCGTGGGAATC\n', '>B4\n', 'TT-GTGGGTATC\n',
   '>B5\n', 'TTCGTGGGTATT\n', '>B6\n','TTCGGGGGTATC\n',
   '>B7\n', 'TT-GTGGGTATC\n', '>B8\n', 'TTCGGGGGAATC\n',
   '>B9\n', 'TTCGGGGGTATC\n','>B10\n', 'TTCGGGGGTATC\n',
   '>B42\n', 'TT-GTGGGTATC\n']

result = [[]]
for x in lst:
    if x.startswith('>'):
        continue
    if x.startswith('$$$'):
        result.append([])
        continue
    x = x.strip()
    if x:
        result[-1].append(x.replace("-", "Z"))
print(result)
```

This avoids assigning any particular significance to the length of any element.

Comment: Just an extension of this problem. If I need just a list where Set1 and Set2 is all in one list ['TCCGGGGGTATC','TCCGTGGGTATC','TCCGTGGGTATC', 'TCCGGGGGTATC',   'TCCGTGGGTATC',CGTGGGTATC','TCCGTGGGTATC', 'TCCGGGGGTATC'.. ], then is this how my code would look like?     result = []
for x in lst:
    if x.startswith('>'):
        result.append([])
        continue
    x = x.strip()
    if x:
        result[-1].append(x.replace("-", "Z"))
print(result)

Comment: You can't really post Python code in comments. But this is obviously not hard. Post a new question if you can't figure it out (link back to this one for context).

Answer (score 2):

You can exploit the smaller length of the headers (and other unwanted items) as the criterion to filter them out. You start by creating a list containing one list and *appending* the items that pass the length test to the inner list.

A new sublist is added to the resulting list when the *separator* `'$$$'` is reached, and the length test is again used to add the remaining items to this new sublist:

```
lst = ['>1\n', 'TCCGGGGGTATC\n', '>2\n', 'TCCGTGGGTATC\n', '>3\n', 'TCCGTGGGTATC\n', '>4\n', 'TCCGGGGGTATC\n', '>5\n', 'TCCGTGGGTATC\n', '>6\n', 'TCCGTGGGTATC\n', '>7\n', 'TCCGTGGGTATC\n', '>8\n', 'TCCGGGGGTATC\n','\n', '$$$\n', '\n', '>B1\n', 'ATCGGGGGTATT\n', '>B2\n', 'TT-GTGGGAATC\n', '>3\n', 'TTCGTGGGAATC\n', '>B4\n', 'TT-GTGGGTATC\n', '>B5\n', 'TTCGTGGGTATT\n', '>B6\n','TTCGGGGGTATC\n', '>B7\n', 'TT-GTGGGTATC\n', '>B8\n', 'TTCGGGGGAATC\n', '>B9\n', 'TTCGGGGGTATC\n','>B10\n', 'TTCGGGGGTATC\n','>B42\n', 'TT-GTGGGTATC\n']

result = [[]]
for x in lst:
    if len(x) > 6:
        result[-1].append(x.strip())
    if x.startswith('$$$'):
        result.append([])
print(result)
# [['TCCGGGGGTATC', 'TCCGTGGGTATC', 'TCCGTGGGTATC', 'TCCGGGGGTATC', 'TCCGTGGGTATC', 'TCCGTGGGTATC', 'TCCGTGGGTATC', 'TCCGGGGGTATC'], ['ATCGGGGGTATT', 'TT-GTGGGAATC', 'TTCGTGGGAATC', 'TT-GTGGGTATC', 'TTCGTGGGTATT', 'TTCGGGGGTATC', 'TT-GTGGGTATC', 'TTCGGGGGAATC', 'TTCGGGGGTATC', 'TTCGGGGGTATC', 'TT-GTGGGTATC']]
```

Comment: Instead of 6, can the code just consider the length of the element eg. [TACG] would be 4

Comment: If all the headers start with `>` that will be a much better criterion, though you'll apparently also want to discard strings which are empty after stripping.

Comment: 5 is maximum length of every other item. 6 guarantees that only your required strings are added